# Showing original source when debugging generated code in GDB

Tags: c++, gdb

I am writing a programming language that compiles to C++, and wish to debug using GDB.  When I debug the programs, I (of course) see the generated code.  Is there a way to hav GDB instead display the source file that created the generated code?

Comment: Never done anything this extreme myself, but you might be able to take advantage of GDB's pretty printer and write some groovy python scripts to do the mapping.

Comment: I'd say "no". At least not without a huge effort which would probably include extending the debug info and a custom gdb..

Comment: With g++ you should be able to do -g to get the debugging symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to hav GDB instead display the source file that created the generated code?

Sure: you must emit `#line` directives into your generated `C++`, and you need to generate already preprocessed source (which you very likely already do) into `.ii` files. Feeding `.ii` file into `g++` will suppress preprocessing, and `g++` will respect any `#line` directives it finds and emit appropriate source location debug info. [Documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Line-Control.html).

Comment: Fascinating! What is the point of the `.ii` file instead of a `.cpp` file though? I tested doing what you said on a small example, and `gdb` seems to handle a regular `.cpp` file with `#line` directives just fine ; I can even put breakpoints in the original source. In what kind of case would you require a GCC-specific `.ii` file, rather than just a `.cpp` file with `#line` directives? I mean, you can turn the `.cpp` file into a `.ii` file using `g++`'s `-E` flag, but at that point why not just use a `.cpp` file?